# Android - Paypal SDK verify a payment

Tags: android, paypal

I'my trying to use `PayPal` payments in my Android app and i've managed so far to get PayPal's response in `onActivityResult` following the [instructions here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md).Now i need to verify the transaction and here is where i fail.This is what i've done so far,

```
   private void verifyPayment(String paymentKey){

    try {

        APIContext apiContext = new APIContext("my_access_token", "my_secret_token", "sandbox");
        Payment payment = Payment.get(apiContext, paymentKey);

    } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

And this is the error log,

```
response-code: 500  details: null
at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.execute(PayPalResource.java:431)
at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.configureAndExecute(PayPalResource.java:295)
at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.configureAndExecute(PayPalResource.java:228)
at com.paypal.api.payments.Payment.get(Payment.java:187)
at com.mob.tr.Names.verifyPayment(Names.java:175)
at com.mob.tr.Names.access$000(Names.java:39)
at com.mob.tr.Names$1.run(Names.java:128)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.paypal.base.exception.HttpErrorException: Response code: 500 Error response: <ns1:XMLFault xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat"><ns1:faultstring xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">java.lang.NullPointerException</ns1:faultstring></ns1:XMLFault>
at com.paypal.base.HttpConnection.executeWithStream(HttpConnection.java:162)
at com.paypal.base.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:65)
at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.execute(PayPalResource.java:417)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-60892637K9684232WLDMQQYA
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
at com.paypal.base.HttpConnection.executeWithStream(HttpConnection.java:132)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not properly added PayPal SDK.

Check this link : [PayPal Sample App](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK)

On the link you will get instructions as well as sample app you can then check and test it from your sandbox environment.

Best of Luck!

Comment: I'm using this dependecy, and i've already managed to get the JSON paypal sends when a transaction is made.The problem appears when i try to verify one payment

Comment: check the sample apk code also, on their site they have mentioned the method